TypeScript unable to use find method
I have this code in my typescript file:
    class Template {
        private templates = [
            {
                name: 'other',
                template: `<h1>Template</h1>`
            }
        ];
    
        public getByName(name: string) {
            return this.templates.find(t => t.name === name)
        }
    }

const t = new Template();
t.getByName('other');

When I try to compile it, I get this error:
error TS2550: Property 'find' does not exist on type '{ name: string; template: string; }[]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

However my lib compiler option is already set like this:
"compilerOptions": {
...
    "target": "es2016",                                  
    "lib": ["es2016", "dom"], 

I just need the array "find" method in TypeScript, I don't know what else to do to get it.

Do you have @type/node installed as a dev dependency?
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29473#issuecomment-1095668802

Thanks, I fixed the issue thanks to your comment.
